# How do I get realtime updates for facebook user actions?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Currently I have implemented facebook realtime updates . But here I am getting only user actions related to movie likes, statuses and normal likes. How can i get actions like music.listens, places checkins, videos watched etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can only get updates for objects listed in here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2

Comment: Say if selected book as read in the facebook, it been not reflected in the callback. Do have any solution for this.

Comment: no, i guess you would have to check that one on your own, on a regular basis